# Change date format with awk command only one first columns of the file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a large text file with logs. After I execute the below awk command, I'm getting below output

```
grep TEST-FIELD test.log | awk '{print $23,$24,$4,$6,$7,$11,$12,$13}'


2020/01/12 08:43:14 TEST-FIELD 10001000 RRRT100 xx.xx.xx.xx [xx-xxxx] xx.xx.xx.xx
2020/01/12 08:43:14 TEST-FIELD 10001000 RRRT100 xx.xx.xx.xx [xx-xxxx] xx.xx.xx.xx
2020/01/12 08:43:14 TEST-FIELD 10001000 RRRT100 xx.xx.xx.xx [xx-xxxx] xx.xx.xx.xx
2020/01/12 08:43:14 TEST-FIELD 10001000 RRRT100 xx.xx.xx.xx [xx-xxxx] xx.xx.xx.xx
```

I need to change the output of the date column ($23) to like this

```
2020-01-12 08:43:14 TEST-FIELD 10001000 RRRT100 xx.xx.xx.xx [xx-xxxx] xx.xx.xx.xx
2020-01-12 08:43:14 TEST-FIELD 10001000 RRRT100 xx.xx.xx.xx [xx-xxxx] xx.xx.xx.xx
2020-01-12 08:43:14 TEST-FIELD 10001000 RRRT100 xx.xx.xx.xx [xx-xxxx] xx.xx.xx.xx
2020-01-12 08:43:14 TEST-FIELD 10001000 RRRT100 xx.xx.xx.xx [xx-xxxx] xx.xx.xx.xx
```

I tried to below command but it not printing proper values at all

```
grep TEST-FIELD test.log | awk  -F"/" '{OFS="/"; $23=strftime("%Y-%m-%d", $23); print $24,$4,$6,$7,$11,$12,$13}'
```

How can I get the correct output only using AWK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your original awk to:

```
awk '{gsub ("/", "-", $23); print $23,$24,$4,$6,$7,$11,$12,$13}'
```

Answer (score 0):

command

```
awk '{x=substr($1,1,4)"-"substr($1,6,2)"-"substr($1,9,2);$1="";print x$0}'  filename
```

output

```
2020-01-12 08:43:14 TEST-FIELD 10001000 RRRT100 xx.xx.xx.xx [xx-xxxx] xx.xx.xx.xx
2020-01-12 08:43:14 TEST-FIELD 10001000 RRRT100 xx.xx.xx.xx [xx-xxxx] xx.xx.xx.xx
2020-01-12 08:43:14 TEST-FIELD 10001000 RRRT100 xx.xx.xx.xx [xx-xxxx] xx.xx.xx.xx
2020-01-12 08:43:14 TEST-FIELD 10001000 RRRT100 xx.xx.xx.xx [xx-xxxx] xx.xx.xx.xx
```